# How to control for non-independence of time in glmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am using a GLMM for a time series dataset, and was wondering if there is a way to add a correlation structure for time?  I have 10 years of data, and have observations on each day.  My concern is that my observations are not independent of each other because each day of data can be affected by the day before or the day after.  How can I do this within a `glmer()` framework? I unfortunately can't use `lme()` or `lmer()` since my response variable is a Poisson distribution and I have both fixed and random effects.

Comment: `library(MASS); help("glmmPQL")`

Comment: Is using a quasi-poisson ok even if I don't have overdispersion in my data? @roland

Comment: Instead of controlling for it, why don't you test to see if it is an issue?  Either an autocorrelation plot or a lag plot could help you determine if time is something that should or shouldn't be controlled.

Comment: Thanks, is there a paper you would recommend @tavrock?